# Visual Studio Code - Auto Hiding Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any setting for auto hiding the Explorer Window in Visual Studio Code **Version 1.0**

At the moment I just pull it back in, but just checking there isnt a nicer way of setting this up to do it automically.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know there is no such option. Instead you can quickly toggle between states using `Ctrl+B`

Comment: thanks guys - maybe a nice extension is in order....;)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You cannot currently auto-hide the explorer. The GitHub issue tracking this is [#3742](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3742).

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (Windows, Linux), <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (OS X) is the keybinding to manually toggle the side bar.

Comment: is there a reason why the shortcut is not the same like opening the explorer?

Comment: will be very helpful and productive like in VS

Answer (score 26):

Went ahead and made an extension for this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=venryx.vscode-vtools

It's not perfect -- it only closes the side-bar when the user changes the selection (eg, clicking or dragging at a new location) -- but it achieves the basic function.

Built-in support is still ideal, but this should help until then.

Comment: Thanks! Works great

Comment: A better UX would be to show sidebar on left edge hover and then hiding it when the focus changes.

Comment: Thanks you. This should get more tractions. Tweeting about this now!

Answer (score 3):

See the extension [Auto Hide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sirmspencer.vscode-autohide)

Settings

- autoHide.autoHideSideBar: Hide the side bar when the user clicks into a text editor. [boolean, default: true]
- autoHide.autoHidePanel: Hide the panel (output, terminal, etc.) when the user clicks into a text editor. [boolean, default: true]
- autoHide.sideBarDelay: How long to wait before hiding the side bar. A delay prevents text from being selected. A longer delay allows the horizontal scroll to adjust to the change in selection before the side bar hiding causes the horizontal scroll to adjust, avoiding conflicts. [number, default: 450]
- autoHide.panelDelay: How long to wait before hiding the panel. Same as for the side bar when the panel is on the side. If the panel is on the bottom, there is no need for delay. [number, default: 300]
- autoHide.hideOnOpen: Hide side bar and panel when VSCode first opens. [boolean, default: true]